# What are the Compiler Options & Other mechanism for reducing the static library size?

Tags: c, gcc, vxworks

What are the Compiler Options & Other mechanism for reducing the static library size?

OS : VxWorks
Compiler : GCC
Language : C

Comment: Do you compile a project with static linked library, or compile a library? Which library you use?

Comment: My deliverable is a static library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-Os` to optimise for smaller code size, and leave out `-g` and any other debug options.

Comment: Apart from -Os are there any other Compiler Options in addition to -Os which might help with size reduction?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really concerned with the executable size after linking a static library then you should also put only one function in each source file (and hence object file). Linkers usually pull entire object files out of a static library during linking.

Comment: Ok. This is good info. Thanks! But, should I modify all my source files, or is there a way for me to tell the compiler to do this by itself?

Comment: AFAIK you'll have to do it by hand, the compiler probably isn't going to be smart enough to know how to properly factor everything into self contained units (consider that two functions may share static data or opaque types). This sort of thing is usually done when the library is started.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to include the static libs in you final image? The static libs are linked into the executable at link time, so unless you are going to make a system with a working compiler/linker you can safely remove the static libraries. Dynamic libs is another story ...

If you need to reduce the size of the static libraries, use "strip" with the right options. "strip mylib.a" without any options should do the right thing, but you might get a smaller library with a few extra options. Be careful so that you don't remove the symbol table from the library since the linker needs this table to do its "magic".

Comment: The strip seem to remove all the symbols. I don't want to end up with no symbols at all. In that way, I will not be able to get any info in case of a crash. I only want the unused symbols to be removed.

Comment: Try: "strip --strip-debug" or "strip --strip-unneeded"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--ffunction-sections` and `--fdata-sections`, which tells gcc to put each function and global data variable in a separate section inside the object. You don't have to modify all your source files.